# getting null for user email - restfb

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I've recently started working on [manual login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1) of facebook. And followed this [blog](http://www.richardnichols.net/2010/06/implementing-facebook-oauth-2-0-authentication-in-java/) to get the access token and using [rest*fb*](http://restfb.com/) to access user information.
Below is the code snippet as mentioned - [Fetching Single Objects](http://restfb.com/#fetching-single-objects):

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(ACCESS_TOKEN, APP_SECRET);
User user = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
```

I'm successfully able to get the user's name, first name and last name but it returns `null` for `email` (`user.getEmail();`).

My facebook app has default permissions as:
[image: permissions]

Anyone help me how can I access the user email?

**UPDATE**

I've been trying the `graph-api` explorer to see what I'm getting for `email`
[image: graph-api explorer]
and it says `Field is empty or disallowed by the access token`. What do I'm supposed to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the user doesn't have his email listed or you aren't requesting the `email` permission in scope.

Check that you have `email` permissions with a request to `me/permissions`

In that blog post mentioned the `email` should be set in the `getLoginRedirectURL`. To ensure this when you go through a login dialog check that the Facebook login dialog asks for email permission.

This is also described in the manual flow

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id={app-id}
   &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}&scope=email`

Comment: how do I request for `email` permission in scope?

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've got certain questions now... what if user edit the preference and uncheck not to provide email? How can I get his email later? Can more than one scope be requested and how?

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
User me = client.fetchObject(yourId, User.class,Parameter.with("fields", "email"));
```

Comment: Can you tell how can I give more parameters?

Comment: Just put all the parameters you want separated by commas eg. ("fields", "email,first_name,last_name") etc

Comment: Here you can find the available fields: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user